# The most efficient Big-O runtime for this?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

If you were considering a node in a trie. Instead of an array of pointers to child nodes, if we use
a binary search tree with the alphabet symbol as key, what is the Big-O runtime to
look up a string of length m?

I would believe this would be O(n) right?

Comment: What is n? You have only defined m as input, so O(n) obviously cannot be right.

Answer (score 1):

## O(M log N)

Let's call the amount of characters in the alphabet N, and the length of the string M.

Every binary tree would be of depth O(log N). We have to traverse such a binary tree a total of M times, once for each character in the string. Therefore, the complexity is O(M log N).

Comment: This is correct under the assumption that the tree is balanced.

Comment: @MoB. The question does specify "most efficient", and the size and keys for the trees are known beforehand, so I do think that's a reasonable assumption to implicitly make.